# Rsync does not exclude files or folders with "[" or "]" in file/folder name

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to Rsync some files and folders to a remote server with the command as:

```
rsync -rtOzv --partial -e ssh /media/external/Media/ user@serverip:/media/external/Media  --exclude-from='/srv/mr/logs/ExcludeList.txt' --log-file=/srv/mr/logs/RSyncLog.txt
```

with `ExcludeList.txt` containing the following:

```
testfolder1
test folder 2
test - folder - 3
test [folder4]
testfile1.txt
test file 2.txt
test - file - 3.txt
test [file4].txt
```

When I run the command, `test [folder4]` and `test [file4].txt` still get transferred to remote folder. How can I exclude the files/folders that contain `[` or `]` in its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page says

```
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

Note the word **patterns**. The exclude list does not consist of mere file names, but patterns. Try backslashes:

```
test \[folder4\]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [rsync man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1), "INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES" section:

> - a '`[`' introduces a character class, such as `[a-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]`.
> - in a wildcard pattern, a backslash can be used to escape a wildcard
>   character, but it is matched literally when no wildcards are present.
>   This means that there is an extra level of backslash removal when a
>   pattern contains wildcard characters compared to a pattern that has
>   none. e.g. if you add a wildcard to "`foo\bar`" (which matches the
>   backslash) you would need to use "`foo\\bar*`" to avoid the "`\b`"
>   becoming just "`b`".

This means that `[file4]` will be treated as a pattern that matches any of the single characters "f", "i", "l", "e", or "4". To get the square-brackets to be treated literally, you need to escape them, like: `test \[file4\].txt`.